# var definitions in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am beginning to use swift and what is the difference between the `!` and `?` when declare vars, for example there are three ways to declare the vars:

```
var one : NSString = ""
var lang : NSString!
var country : NSString?
```

What means the symbols in the end of each var?

Thanks!

Comment: Contains something. Must contain something when used. May contain something when used. You should google this kind of thing before asking it here...